# Excel formula to track streak

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been using a table to give myself a daily grade on some tasks, each row is laid out like

Do stretches:| A | A | B | C | A did yoga | F forgot | A | B | A | B | A

I would like to add a cell that calculates my current streak of days that are either A or B, which for the example, would be five. I've been doing it for a few months so my data ranges from columns S to CK. So if I look at row 7, the formula should look at cells S7:CK7, and count from the back how many consecutive days start with A or B. Then tomorrow I should be able to insert a new column, and the formula should then track S7:CL7.

It would also be nice to have a formula that calculates the longest streak within that row too.

Any suggestions on how I would lay this out?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome. Please note that we are not a script writing service. Can you please share with us, by editing your post, the research that you have done and what you have tried so far in trying to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve this without writing a script, this can be done very easily using an XML table (highlight your data - Home - Format as Table). Note however, that Excel defaults to XML tables that are laid out with formulas copied vertically rather than horizontally, so the simplest layout would be to transpose your data and give yourself a grade for each day in a new row rather than a new column.

Once your data is in an XML table you can just add a day at the bottom of the table and Excel will automatically add a row to your table.

Below is an example of how this would work. In one column of the table you create a counter, which is just an IF formula adding one to the counter if you got an A or a B that day; otherwise it resets to 0. In row 18 that formula would be **=IF(OR(B18="A",B18="B"),C17+1,0)**

Then you'll want a MAX formula referencing the counter column of your table -- in the example below the Table is named Table3, and the formula is **=MAX(Table3[Counter])**

[image]

(the Day 0 entry is just there to initialize the counter at 0)